# Trying to make a paneled spaghetti chart with highlighted line

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a graph like the one found here at the very bottom: https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/spaghetti.html

unfortunately I have a character variable instead of a numeric one for the x axis (I have four years by months), and I don't get the grey lines as in that graph per panel. Does anyone know how else to obtain that graph?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more details/an example, but it seems like you should be able to do this using the *gghiglight* package. There's a facetted example half way down [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html).